# entries in auth.log are +??? I am not sure what it means

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu-10.04

I have following entries in /var/log/auth.log

```
Jan 24 06:37:54 server1 su[9508]: Successful su for nobody by root
Jan 24 06:37:54 server1 su[9508]: + ??? root:nobody
```

does it point to some problem I am not sure.So let me know if it is some thing I need to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a cron job, because:

- User root dropped privileges and became "nobody" to run a cronjob. Check with `crontab -l` while being root. If there's no cronjob, you might want to worry.
- Log entries (although they might be faked of course) around 06:25 AM tend to be cronjobs, updatedb commands etc.

Comment: Ok crontab -l gives only  
`8 9 * * * /etc/webmin/cron/tempdelete.pl #Delete Webmin temporary files`

Comment: Look in /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily etc. too. Forgot to mention this.